# Angular JS injection in JSP Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jsp

I am new to Angular JS.I have a Spring WEB-MVC application where I using angular js in jsp pages.Find below the coding details:

home.jsp:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
      pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
         <title>Home</title>
         <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/task.js"></script> 
     </head>
     <body ng-app="taskApp" ng-controller="taskController">
       <div>
         <button ng-click="loadAllTask()">Show All Tasks</button>
       </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Task.js file :

```
  var taskManagerModule = angular.module('taskApp',[]).controller('taskController',function($scope,$http){
     $scope.loadAllTask = function(){
     alert('loadAllTask got invoked'); 
     }
  });
```

I am getting following error in browser console

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module taskApp due to:
       [$injector:nomod] Module 'taskApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it
```

Due to this error `loadAllTask()` not getting invoked.

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this???

Comment: check in browser dev tools network if task.js is loading....if not, path is wrong Also double check all your code for syntax errors that might cause a component to not register properly

Comment: The path for `src="../js/task.js"` is wrong. and how config to load resources in spring?

Comment: check the src="../js/task.js"